# ssh from external ip address not working

Tags: networking, router, ssh, port-forwarding, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to ssh into my wsl from a remote machine.

1. I have setup the ssh forwarding from Windows to wsl. I can now ssh into my wsl through my internal IP address 192.168.2.101
2. I have setup the router port forwarding. I tried to scan my port with some online port scanning tools. Some of them tells me that my 22 port is on (https://www.portchecktool.com/, https://hackertarget.com/nmap-online-port-scanner/), some of them doesn't (http://www.dnstools.ch/port-scanner.html). The router I'm using is a vodafone easybox 805. I forward port 22 to my PC desktop on it. I am not sure whether the port forwarding function is valid on this free router but it do has the port forwarding funtionality.
3. I have opened the windows firewall for port 22. I'm not sure whether it's successful or not though.
4. I have looked into the ssh log and I'm sure that the connect request doesn't reach wsl. Not sure whether it reaches windows or not.

I tried to ssh to it through a mobile hotspot and another computer with my external ip. The results shows "connection timed out".

Comment: is the firewall on the windows system up?. Easy test, drop the windows firewall and see if it works.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add details about your router and how exactly you configured the port forwarding. Run a network sniffer like Wireshark on your Windows system to find out if the connection requests reach your PC. Or do this on a Linux system and configure the port forwarding to this Linux system instead of the Windows system. You could also boot your PC with a live Linux.